# Switching views within the same controller whilst retaining scope data

Tags: angularjs, scope, nested, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a page of data that can be viewed as a list or as markers on a map. It also has filtering in the sidebar. I currently have this structured as separate map and list pages but I want to merge them so that the filters remain when switching views.

I have tried using `ui-router` but due to my markup I cannot keep the filtering within a parent state, as per my question here: [How do I show multiple views in an abstract state template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287030/how-do-i-show-multiple-views-in-an-abstract-state-template)

My current markup is like this:

```
<div class="main-container" ng-controller="PlanningCtrl" data-county-parish-id="1478">
    <main class="page-content">
        <!-- toggles between map and list views -->
        <a href="/map">View map</a>

        <!-- main content view here -->
        <appl-list></appl-list>

        <!-- <appl-map></appl-map> -->
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <div refine-results info="refine" id="SearchForm" class="refine-search"></div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

The data array is within the controller as `$scope.filteredApplications` and on each page this is filtering and displaying fine within each directive.

I guess my question is: how can I toggle between the two `<appl-*>` directives and display the same filtered records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if with your directives and set value based on a scope variable.

Your controller would have something like:

```
$scope.show = 'List'
```

Then you'd have this in your HTML:

```
    <appl-list ng-if="show==='List'></appl-list>

    <appl-map ng-if="show==='Map'></appl-map>
```

Then you'd toggle the value of $scope.show between 'List' and 'Map' based on some event.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, solution is really very close. We will profit from UI-Router native design. Here is a full story ***(with working example)***:

#### [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

So, what we should do, is to properly use view data inheritance - which works well with some reference property, e.g. **`Model : {}`** declared on the parent state (root view)

```
controller('rootController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.Model = {SomeProperty : "xxx"}; // root controller creates it
})
```

We can (could) also introduce the some super root state, and easily inject that into each state family super parent

```
.state('root', {
  template: "<div ui-view></div>",
  controller: "rootController"
}

// any grand parent of some state hierarchy

.state("business", {
  parent: "root",
  ...
.state("athorization", {
  parent: "root"
```

and later any controller (any because, we inherit from root unnamed view) can do filtering

```
$scope.Model.Filter = {...}
```

And any other controller can use that filter

```
$scope.filterPlanning = function() {
  var data = ...
  var filter = $scope.Model.Filter;
  // filter magic
  ...

  return filteredOutput;
}
```

Similar technique, including examples in TypeScript could be found here ***(also has working example)***

#### [Angular Digest cycle being ran but ng-bind value not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32917945/1679310)